# Replacing Value in Subelement of dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I got a dataset of entries with the IDs of gasoline stations and their current prices (diesel, e5 and e10). However, some of the gas stations are not selling every product and therefore the value for the field in the array is 'false'

In detail the dict looks like this:

```
data = {
    "005056ba-7cb6-1ed2-bceb-662ba1a94d1f": {
        "status": "open",
        "e5": 1.839,
        "e10": 1.779,
        "diesel": 'false'
    },
    "005056ba-7cb6-1ed2-bceb-5332ab168d12": {
        "status": "open",
        "e5": 1.719,
        "e10": 'false',
        "diesel": 'false'
    },
    "00060723-0001-4444-8888-acdc00000001": {
        "status": "open",
        "e5": 1.839,
        "e10": 1.779,
        "diesel": 2.179
    }
}
```

To further process the response of the request I need to have all prices set to doubles, but since there are those 'false' values it wont accept it.

How can I replace all 'false' values to 0 to ensure that all the prices can be read as doubles?

Comment: That looks like a dict not an array. This isn't a discussion forum or a turtorial. Please take the time to read [ask], [mre] and other topics found in the [help].

Comment: what do you want to do with the values that are 'false'? Do you want to convert them to doubles as well? What values should they have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```py
def sanitize_data(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        for k, v in value.items():
            if v == "false":
                data[key][k] = 0.0

    return data
```

Example Result

```json
{
    "00060723-0001-4444-8888-acdc00000001": {
        diesel: 2.179,
        e10: 1.779,
        e5: 1.839,
        status: "open"
    },
    "005056ba-7cb6-1ed2-bceb-5332ab168d12": {
        diesel: 0,
        e10: 0,
        e5: 1.719,
        status: "open"
    },
    "005056ba-7cb6-1ed2-bceb-662ba1a94d1f": {
        diesel: 0,
        e10: 1.779,
        e5: 1.839,
        status: "open"
    }
}
```